# QML Tumbler looses vertical mouse focus

Tags: qt, qml

When I create a tumbler widget in QML, I can grab it, and change the contents. As soon as I leave the widget with my mouse in vertical direction, the tumbler stops changing its contents. It works fine if I leave the widget to the left or right. In that case, I can operate the tumbler even when the mouse leaves the QML window.
Is there anything I missed?

Example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Rectangle {
    width: 1000
    height: 600
    Tumbler {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: 24
        width: 30
        height: 100
    }
}
```

I'm using QT 6.2.1 and tried it on Kubuntu 20.04 and Yocto Dunfell.
I tried the same thing with a QML Dial. Herewith I can leave the widget in all directions, and it still reacts to my mouse movement.

Comment: That seems like a bug. Can you please report it: bugreports.qt.io

Comment: Reported to bugreports.qt.io QTBUG-110008